# featured image different style on the list and on single post

Tags: post-thumbnails

please take a look at my test site -> http://www.randomguy.hekko24.pl/pl/

I managed to change a featured image style on the list of posts but then it is also changed when you click the full post. What I want to get is small thumbnail in the list of posts as it is now, and larger image in full post. Is it possible? Like two classes/containers for list and single post view?
If it is possible I would like also to change a title style for list and single post.

Something like it is here: https://oscarliang.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you installed twentytwelve theme, So follow there steps

Open file content.php in root folder theme and find

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

change to

```
if ( is_single() ) :
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
else :
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
endif;
```

Comment: thanks! This is probably what I need, can I do the same with title? Same formula with the condition? Can I add class container there to specify css for both images?

Answer (score 0):

Head over to your template's folder, and find the file named `content.php`, open it using any text editor.

Now, find the `DIV` with the following class : `excerpt-feature-image`

I assume there is a code to call the proper image size for your post there. It must be something like :

`<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' ); ?>`

If you want the full size image (or medium/large) you need to change the `thumbnail` to the size you want to have. For example, you can try:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>`

The exact code depends on your theme, but the process is the same.